# How to add a new column at the end of the table?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn, columns, threeparttable

Could someone please show me how to add a new column at the end of the table?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, 
            threeparttable}       % <---
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{2pt}    % <---
\setlength\lightrulewidth{1.2pt}  % <---

\setcellgapes{3pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\usepackage{isotope}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\arrayrulecolor{teal}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2}                % <===
    \DeclareCaptionFont{teal}{\color{teal}\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont} % <===
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} % <---
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht] \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\thetable{3}
\caption{XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX}

\begin{tabular}{ l d{3.1} d{1.1} }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{XXXXXXX XXXXX}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{XXXX XXXXXX}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{XX\(^a\)}\\
\midrule
  
XXX & 8.2 & 1.2  \\
  
XXX & 305.2 & 1.1  \\

XXXXX & 189.3 & 0.6 \\

XXXX & 62.3 & 0.1 \\
 
XXXX XXXX & 2.3  & 0.4 \\

XXXXX XXXXX & 39.5 & 1.2 \\
  
XXX  & 0.3 & 1.2 \\

XXXXXX XXXXXXXX & 9.2 & 0.9 \\

XXXXXXXX & 8.9 & 1.4 \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{XXXXX XXXX} \\
\cmidrule{1-1}

XXXXXXX & 9.2 & 0.5 \\
XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXX 90 & 562.3 & 2 \\
XXXX XXXXX XXXXXX 10 & 98.2 & 1.2 \\
XX XXXXXXX XXXXXXX 30 & 1.9 & 0.1 \\
XXXXXX XXXXX 10 & 90.3 & 1.5 \\
XXXXX XXXXXXX 20 & 9.8 & 1.9 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}[para]    % <---

\(^a\)XX = XXXXX XXXXXXXXX
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simple. add one more column specifier and than in table body add at end of rows ampersands and contents of the last cells of in rows.

Comment: Could you please show me how it`s done?

Comment: Please make yourself a bit more familiar with writing tables by LaTeX. Read some introductory text about this, for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables.  I don't know, which type of column you like to add (`c`, `l` or `r`, or something else). Just add selected type to existed (`l d{3.1} d{1.1}`) ...

Comment: Thank you for replying. Of course you are correct, but it`s been really busy lately so in addition of searching for information, I decided to reach out to the expertise on StackExchange, saving me from using valuable time. I gain a lot of knowledge from the answers I get in here. Have a nice day!

Comment: Reading text in given link require les than quarter of hour. Spend it for this is good investment for your future writing text and tables using LaTeX.

Comment: @Svein is this what you're looking for? https://ibb.co/GR2kz7w

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is what you're looking for:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, 
            threeparttable}       % <---
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{2pt}    % <---
\setlength\lightrulewidth{1.2pt}  % <---

\setcellgapes{3pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\usepackage{isotope}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\arrayrulecolor{teal}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uc}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2}                % <===
    \DeclareCaptionFont{teal}{\color{teal}\fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont} % <===
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} % <---
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht] \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\thetable{3}
\caption{XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX}

\begin{tabular}{ l r r r}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{XXXXXXX XXXXX}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{XXXX XXXXXX}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{XX\(^a\)}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{XX\(^{a+1}\)}\\
\midrule
  
XXX & 8.2 & 1.2 & 1.2+1 \\
  
XXX & 305.2 & 1.1 & 1.1+1 \\

XXXXX & 189.3 & 0.6 & 0.6+1\\

XXXX & 62.3 & 0.1 &0.1+1\\
 
XXXX XXXX & 2.3 & 0.4 & 0.4+1\\

XXXXX XXXXX & 39.5 & 1.2 & 1.2+1\\
  
XXX  & 0.3 & 1.2 & 1.2+1\\

XXXXXX XXXXXXXX & 9.2 & 0.9 & 0.9+1\\

XXXXXXXX & 8.9 & 1.4 & 1.4+1\\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{XXXXX XXXX} \\
\cmidrule{1-1}

XXXXXXX & 9.2 & 0.5 & 0.5+1\\
XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXX 90 & 562.3 & 2 & 2+1\\
XXXX XXXXX XXXXXX 10 & 98.2 & 1.2 & 1.2+1\\
XX XXXXXXX XXXXXXX 30 & 1.9 & 0.1 & 0.1+1\\
XXXXXX XXXXX 10 & 90.3 & 1.5 & 1.5+1\\
XXXXX XXXXXXX 20 & 9.8 & 1.9 & 1.9+1\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}[para]    % <---

\(^a\)XX = XXXXX XXXXXXXXX
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Note for the future**: since nobody is here to steal what you accomplished, you should avoid writing `Xs` instead of the content that you really want to be displayed on your document.
Somebody in the future may need the same things that you asked and they could easily find it on the search bar :D
Have a great day!